# How do I set the min-height of a div to the height of another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the `min-height` of `#wrapper` to the height of `#sidebar` which does not have a fixed height.

So, something like the following. I am not adept with JavaScript so please don't laugh if it's way off.

```
var sidebarHeight = jQuery('#sidebar').height;
jQuery('#wrapper').css('min-height', sidebarHeight);
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why min-height, should its height go beyond its parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var sidebarHeight = jQuery('#sidebar').height(); //height() not height
```

and ensure function should be in  `$(document).ready(function(){...  });`

As per your need

```
jQuery('#sidebar').outerHeight(); 
if(jQuery('#sidebar').is(':visible')){ // if sidebar visible min-height is applied to wrapper
    jQuery('#wrapper').css('min-height', sidebarHeight); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I only missed the parenthesis. This is a big moment for a JavaScript beginner like me.

Comment: @Desi before posting question search around stackoverflow you will get answer

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery outerHeight() as it will take in consideration the margin also

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
       var sidebarHeight = jQuery('#sidebar').outerHeight();
       jQuery('#wrapper').css('min-height', sidebarHeight);

       $(window).resize(function(){ //for responsive site ensure that min-height is changed 
        var sidebarHeight = jQuery('#sidebar')..outerHeight();
       jQuery('#wrapper').css('min-height', sidebarHeight);  
       });
     });
```